# Uniform Convergence of a function, not a sequence of functions

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

I need to know what the meaning is, mathematically, of the phrase, f approaches zero when x approaches infinity, uniformly in a certain set.

For example, see Jordan Lemma.

What is mean for a function to be uniformly convergent?

Does it mean:

We say that f approaches 0, uniformly on the set E as x approaches infinity, if given an arbitrarily small positive number epsilon, there exist a number N that depends only on epsilon, such that when x is greater than N, f(x) is less than epsilon in absolute value for any x in E.

Is the above correct?

Here's an example from *Basic Complex Analysis* by Jerrold Marsden (1973). Page 235.

> If $f(z)$ approaches $0$ when the absolute value of $z$ approaches $\infty$, uniformly in $\arg z$, and $\arg z$ between $0$ and $\pi$, then the contour integral over $\gamma(\rho)$ $$\oint_{\gamma(\rho)} \exp( i a z) f(z) \mathrm d z$$ approaches $0$ when $\rho$ approaches $\infty$.  Here $\gamma(\rho)(\theta) = \rho \exp (i \theta)$ and $\theta$ between $0$ and $\pi$.

Comment: A single function cannot be "uniformly convergent", but it can be "uniformly _continuous_". Perhaps you're confusing the two c-words?

Comment: It could be. So we have to assume,  that uniformly on Jordan Lemma means uniformly continuos? Thanks

Comment: If you give a reference to the text you find that wording in, you have a much better chance that someone will be able to explain what it means.

Comment: OK.  Basic Complex Analysis by Jerrold Marsden. Page 235. 1973. If f(z) approaches zero when the absolute value of z approches infinity, uniformly in arg z, and arg z between zero and pi, then the contour integral of exp( i a z) f(z) over gamma of rho approaches zero when rho approaches infinity.Gamma of rho (theta) =rho exp (i theta) and theta between 0 and pi.

Comment: Problems involving the statements about limits often benefit from using [mathematical notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).  See the links in that introduction to more advanced syntax when future needs arise.

Comment: I've tried to convert your Comment's wording into mathematical notation.  More notation could be used, e.g. "as $z$ approaches $\infty$" could be "as $z \to \infty$", but I tried to largely preserve your sentence structure.  Feel free to improve or roll back my edit.

Comment: Suppose that $f(z)\to 0$ when $|z|\to \infty$, {\it uniformly} in $\text{arg} z$, $0 \leq \text{arg} z \leq \pi$ and if $f(z)$ is analitic when $|z| > \text{c}$, c constant, $0 \leq \text{arg} z \leq \pi$, then,
\[ \int_{\gamma_{\rho}} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} a z} f(z) \mathrm{d}(z) \to 0\]
when $\rho \to \infty$, where $\gamma_{\rho}(\theta) = \rho \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}z}$, and$0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$.

Comment: See the use of the word uniformly in the text of Jordan's Lemma. In my opinion it does not mean unifromly continous, nor uniformly convergent. It means that in the definition of limits, {\delta} does not depends on $z$, only in $\epsilon}. Moreover in the book of Whittaker and Watson, A course of Modern Analysis there is a definition of "uniformly" see page 52, 3.5 for the concept of uniformly.

Comment: I am correct? I do agree with Betty Mock on her comments about unifromly. Also. see meaning of uniformly differentiable on this forum.